# I exported via mysqldump to a file. How do I find out the file encoding of the file?

Tags: linux, unicode, ubuntu, mysql

Given a text file in ubuntu (or debian unix in general), how do I find out the file encoding of the file ? Can I run **od** or **hexdump** on it to fingerprint its encoding ? What should I be looking out for ?

Answer (score 1):

There are many tools to do this. Try a web search for "detect encoding".  Here are some of the tools I found:

- The **Internationalizations Classes for Unicode** (ICU) are a great place to start. See especially their page on [Character Set Detection](http://userguide.icu-project.org/conversion/detection).
- **Chardet** is a Python module to guess the encoding
  of a file. See chardet.feedparser.org
- The *nix command-line tool **file**    detects file types, but might also    detect encodings if mentioned in the    file (e.g. if there's a mime-type    notation in
  the file). See `man file`
- Perl modules **Encode::Detect** and    **Encode::Guess** .
- Someone asked a similar question in StackOverflow. Search for the question, **PHP: Detect encoding and make everything UTF-8**. That's in the context of fetching files from the net and using PHP, but you could write a command-line PHP script.

Note well what the ICU page says about character set detection: "Character set detection is ..., at best, an imprecise operation using statistics and heuristics...."  In my experience the problem domain makes a big difference in how easy or difficult the job is. Don't forget that it's possible that the octets in a file can be of ambiguous encoding, *i.e.* sensibly interpreted using multiple different encodings. They can also be of mixed encoding, *i.e.* different subsets of the octets make sense interpreted in different encodings.  This is why there's not a single command-line tool I can recommend which always does the job.

If you have a single file and you just want to get it into a known encoding, my trick is to open the file with a text editor which can import using a bunch of different encodings, such as TextWrangler or OpenOffice.org. First, open the file and let the editor guess the encoding.  Take a look at the result. If you aren't satisfied with it, guess an encoding, open the file with the editor specifying that encoding, and take a look at the result. Then save as a known encoding, e.g. UTF-16.

Answer (score 0):

You can use enca. Enca is a small command line tool for encoding detection and convertion.

You can install it at debian / ubuntu by:

> apt-get install enca

In order to use it, just call

> enca FILENAME

Also see the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/enca) for more information.